# Occupied file system space not decreased despite deleting folder

Tags: centos, disk-usage

This is on a CentOS 7 installation.

- The shared folder is in `/dev/sbd1` mounted on `/data`
- Capacity is 4 TB. After deleting the folder it should show 1.1TB occupied space, but it is showing 2.2TB.
- Deletion was done from shared folder which was mounted in a different workstation by clicking on "Move to trash"
- I checked

  ```
  /home/username/.local/ 
  /home/
  ```

  and there is not trash directory.
- I also tried to install `trash_cli` via `yum install trash_cli`. It didn't help.

Where to check or how to find where the deleted data is, and why even after deleting it is stil in same size?

Comment: Output of `du /data`?

Comment: when i do du -sh  /data it is 2.2TB

Comment: I asked without `-s` for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Disk space isn't freed until all handles to it are closed so it's likely that some process still has the deleted files opened so they haven't been pruned yet.

To list open files recursively use `lsof +D /data` or `lsof +D /data | grep deleted` to only show open files that are deleted

You'll then want to kill or restart any process that is holding open a deleted file.